How to detect overfitting in ML for regression
I applied Xgboost to my dataset which has about 50,000 observations. I split the dataset into 80/20 and use 5-fold cross validation. Below are the results:
Train Set
R$^2$: 0.985
MAE: 0.083
MSE: 0.015
MAPE: 2.944%
RMSE: 0.124
Test Set
R$^2$: 0.956
MAE: 0.120
MSE: 0.044
MAPE: 4.090%
RMSE: 0.209
5-fold Cross Validation
Train Accuracy: 0.942
Test Accuracy: 0.937
The discrepancies among four evaluation metrics are greater than those of accuracy. Should I prioritize the evaluation metrics or the results from cross-validation? Is there a general guideline indicating that if the difference exceeds a certain threshold, it could signal overfitting?

You cannot compare two different metrics directly. For example, you cannot compare your MAE score with your accuracy score because they have different theories and math behind them.
However, you can compare the MAE score of your training set with that of your test set. In your case, the test scores performed poorer relative to the training set. This is actually expected. Since the difference between them is not that great, it indicates a good fit also.
You are already using two methods to validate your model's performance:

Hold-out
k-fold cross validation

My suggestions are as follows:

First, try increasing k and observe how the metrics change.
Second, there are hyperparameters in the XGBoost model that you can utilize to add extra protection against overfitting, such as eta, gamma, max_depth, and subsample.

You can check XGBoost documentation for more information.

I knew that. I would like to know whether there is a threshold value for each metric and accuracy. If the difference of a metric is beyond the threshold, it indicates the sign of overfitting.

There are no specific thresholds related to your question. You can only take precautions. If your model produces good metric scores, it could indicate either overfitting or a good fit. What you can do is ensure that these good metric scores are valid by performing validations, which you have already done to some extent. In addition to that, you can take further measures, such as utilizing the model's hyperparameters to avoid overfitting, as I suggested in my earlier answer.

Is my model overfitting or not?
